# Vagrant puppet provision failure. Error msg: "The `puppet` binary appears not to be in the PATH of the guest. ... "

Tags: vagrant, puppet, ubuntu-16.04, vagrantfile

## Vagrant puppet provision failure with ubuntu/xenial64.

**Error message:**

> This could be because the PATH is not properly setup or perhaps Puppet
>   is not installed on this guest. Puppet provisioning can not continue
>   without Puppet properly installed.

---

**Vagrantfile:**
**Note: The below setup worked fine with ubuntu/trusty64**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.hostname = "elasticsearch-learn"
  config.vm.box_url = "init"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 9200
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5601, host: 5601

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
      puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  end

end
```

**Vagrant running directory structure:**

```
vagrant_devenv (master)*$ tree -L 2
.
├── README.rst
├── Vagrantfile
├── installpuppet.sh
├── puppet
│   ├── manifests
│   └── modules
├── requirements.txt
└── ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
```

**Optional:**

*Just for reference, if needed. I use my [old git repo](https://github.com/arjun911code/vagrant_devenv) and make local changes for each project. Its not updated for xenial64 but the puppet packages are same. But you can find the puppet manifests and modules I generally use there*

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to puppet was not found in ubuntu/xenial64. So included a step in installing puppet-agent before puppet provisioning.

I changed the Vagrantfile with an additional step to install puppet-agent before the puppet provision step.

> config.vm.provision :"shell", path: "installpuppet.sh"

The updated Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.hostname = "elasticsearch-learn"
  config.vm.box_url = "init"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 9200
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5601, host: 5601

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = "1024"
  end

  config.vm.provision :"shell", path: "installpuppet.sh"
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
      puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  end

end
```

*installpuppet.sh* contents:

```
apt update
apt install -y puppet
```

Then perform the usual ***'vagrant up'***

This worked for me! Hope it helps. Let me know if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try this befores config.vm.provision:

```
web_config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y puppet"
```

Just install puppet before run.

Full sample:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
      config.vm.define :web do |web_config|

      web_config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y puppet"
      web_config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
            puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
            puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
      end
  end
end
```